# remove '#' symbol from the beginning of the string in java

Tags: java, opencsv

Sample data in csv file

```
##Troubleshooting DHCP Configuration
#Module 3: Point-to-Point Protocol (PPP)
##Configuring HDLC Encapsulation 

Hardware is HD64570
```

So i want to get the lines as

```
#Troubleshooting DHCP Configuratin
Module 3: Point-to-Point Protocol(PPP)
#Configuring HDLC Encapsulation

Hardware is HD64570
```

I have written sample code

```
public class ReadCSV {

public static BufferedReader br = null;

  public static void main(String[] args) {

      ReadCSV obj = new ReadCSV();
    obj.run();

  }

  public void run() {





                String sCurrentLine;

                try {
                    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\compare\\Genre_Subgenre.csv"));

                    try {
                        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                            if(sCurrentLine.charAt(0) == '#'){

                            System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }





 }

}
```

I am getting below error

##Troubleshooting DHCP Configuration 
 #Module 3: Point-to-Point Protocol (PPP)
 ##Configuring HDLC Encapsulation 
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out        of range: 0
 at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
 at example.ReadCSV.main(ReadCSV.java:19)

Please suggest me how to do this?

Comment: Do you have any code you have tried we can analyze?

Comment: What options have you considered. What research have you done? Why didn't what you try work?

Comment: if # contains as first letter in each line why don't you use substring?

Comment: See the answer in my post below: in your if `System.out.println(sCurrentLine.substring(1));`

Answer (score 1):

Steps:

1. Read the CSV file line by line
2. Use `line.replaceFirst("#", "")` to remove the first # from each line
3. Write the modified lines to an output stream (file or String) which suites you

Comment: I think if you have a line like `stuff something #comment` it will replace the #

Comment: Thanks Athanor for noticing, But since the requirement is unclear whether what the user wants, I stick to the assumption that he wants the first `#` to be replaced :)

Answer (score 0):

If the variable `s` contains the content of the CSV file as String

```
s = s.replace("##", "#");
```

will replace all the occurrencies of '##" with '#'

Comment: Your answer `s = s.replace("##", "#");` wont work on the 2nd line, where the single `#` need to replaced with ` `

Comment: it also repaces ## anywhere in the string

Answer (score 0):

You need something like `String line=buffer.readLine()`

Check the first character of the line with `line.charAt(0)=='#'`

Get the new String with `String newLine=line.substring(1)`

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather trivial question. Rather than do the work for you, I'll outline the steps that you need to take without gifting you the answer.

1. Read in a file line by line
2. Take the first line and check if the first character of this line is a `#` - If it is, create a substring of this line excluding the first character ( or use `fileLine.replaceFirst("#", "");` )
3. Store this line somewhere in an array like data structure or simply replace the current variable with the edited one ( `fileLine = fileLine.replaceFirst("#", "");` )
4. Repeat until no more lines left from file.
5. If you want to add these changes to the file, simply overwrite the old file with the new lines (e.g. Using a steam reader and setting second parameter to false would overwrite)

Make an attempt and show us what you have tried, people will be more likely to help if they believe you have attempted the problem yourself thoroughly first.

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestion and help. I will try and show code to all of you if i am succeeded

Answer (score 0):

```
package stackoverflow.q_25054783;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class RemoveHash {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String [] strArray = new String [3];
        strArray[0] = "##Troubleshooting DHCP Configuration";
        strArray[1] = "#Module 3: Point-to-Point Protocol (PPP)";
        strArray[2] = "##Configuring HDLC Encapsulation"; 
        System.out.println("Original array: " + Arrays.toString(strArray));

        for (int i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++) {
            strArray[i] = strArray[i].replaceFirst("#", ""); 
        }
        System.out.println("Updated array: " + Arrays.toString(strArray));
    }
}

//Output:
//Original array: [##Troubleshooting DHCP Configuration, #Module 3: Point-to-Point Protocol (PPP), ##Configuring HDLC Encapsulation]
//Updated array: [#Troubleshooting DHCP Configuration, Module 3: Point-to-Point Protocol (PPP), #Configuring HDLC Encapsulation]
```

Answer (score 0):

OpenCSV reads CSV file line by line and gives you an array of strings, where each string is one comma separated value, right? Thus, you are operating on a string.

You want to remove '#' symbol from the beginning of the string (if it is there). Correct?

Then this should do it:

```
CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("yourfile.csv"));
String [] nextLine;
while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
    if (nextLine[0].charAt(0) == '#') {
        nextLine[0] = nextLine[0].substring(1, nextLine[0].length());
    }
}
```

Replacing the first '#' symbol on each of the lines in the CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

```
private List<String> getFileContentWithoutFirstChar(File f){
    try (BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(f), Charset.forName("UTF-8")))){
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(String line = input.readLine(); line != null; line = input.readLine()) {
            lines.add(line.substring(1));
        }

        return lines

    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
        return null;
    }
}

private void writeFile(List<String> lines, File f){
    try(BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(f), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))){
        for(String line : lines){
            bw.write(content);
        }
        bw.flush();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

main(){
    File f = new File("file/path");
    List<Stirng> lines = getFileContent(f);
    f.delete();
    writeFile(lines, f);
}
```